# ng-repeat unknown number of nested elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm wondering if there is a simple solution to this type of problem.

I have an object comment, which can in turn contain comments, and those comments can also contain comments ...and this can go on for a unknown number of cycles.

Here is an example of the data structure:

```
var comment = {
   text : "",
   comments: [
      { text: "", comments : []},
      { text: "", comments: [
         { text: "", comments : []},
         { text: "", comments : []}
         { text: "", comments : []}
      ]}
   ]
}
```

Lets say for 2 levels of comments I would write:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
   {{comment.text}}
   <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
      {{comment.text}}
   </div>
</div>
```

How would I implent my divs for "n" level of nested comments ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a generic partial so you can recursively call and render it using `ng-include`.

```
<div ng-include="'partialComment.html'" ng-model="comments"></div>
```

Here is the partial:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in comments">
      {{c.text}}
      <div ng-switch on="c.comments.length > 0">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
          <div ng-init="comments = c.comments;" ng-include="'partialComment.html'"></div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The data model should be a list `var comments = [{ ... }]`.

I created a demo for you and hope it helps.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqIzbR6Rgi5qbnAocFf5?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Would there be a way to hide all elements except the first set in the recursion ?

Comment: @guiomie you can check the $first parameter in the ng repeater .

Comment: what I mean is hiding all elements that arent in the first array, not the first elements of each array. So only the elements of the first comments array are not hidden...

Comment: @guiomie Maybe you can extend your data model to add a new field called isVisible, and make it pure data driven.

Comment: This is the avenue I have taken. THe issue is when I use ng-show, all the elements will be showed...

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive directive. Something like [this](http://itarato.blogspot.ch/2013/01/angularjs-and-recursive-template.html), or probably better [this](http://gistflow.com/posts/843-creating-recursive-templates-in-angular-js).

Comment: The [gistflow](http://gistflow.com/posts/843-creating-recursive-templates-in-angular-js) link is dead.