# Unknown number of sublists with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on building a tool to help users navigate our website.  The AngularJS function receives a JSON object from another service and then prints out an html5 list.

The html should look like

```
<ul>
<li>Root
  <ul>
      <li>
        Child 2
        <ul>
          <li>Grand Child 1</li>
          <li>Grand Child 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Doing a simple nested ng-repeat (as seen below) will easily give me a single set of children, but I'm not sure as what the best way to setup a function with Angular in which I have an unknown number of sub elements.

```
<li ng-repeat="node in nodes">
    <a href="#">{{node.title}}</a>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="child in node.children">
            <a href="#">{{child.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

An example JSON object:

```
{ 
    title:'University',
    children: [
        { 
            title:'College of Engineering',
            children: [
                { title:'Computer Science' },
                { title:'Electrical Engineering' },
                { title:'Chemical Engineering' },
                { title:'Biological Engineering' },
                { title:'Mechanical Engineering' },
                { title:'Civil Engineering' },
                { title:'Environmental Engineering' }
            ]
        },
        { title:'College of Liberal Arts' },
        { title:'College of Science' },
        { title:'College of Math' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What looks like the JSON object?

Comment: @Blackhole: I added an example JSON object, the real one may have much deeper nesting than the example.

Comment: An idea: create a custom directive, a kind of `recursiveRepeat`. I'll show you an example later if you want.

Comment: google `angular recursive` ... here's one fairly straightforward method  http://jsbin.com/acibiv/3/edit

Comment: @Blackhole: That would be appreciated.  I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm trying to keep things as idiomatic as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-repeat unknown number of nested elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294932/ng-repeat-unknown-number-of-nested-elements)

Comment: @zsong: It most certainly is.  I wasn't able to find that earlier, thank you that got me what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example to use the recursive partial view to display the list

*partial.html*:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in data">
      {{c.title}}
      <div ng-switch on="c.children.length > 0">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
          <div ng-init="data = c.children;" ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4HTm8iqlqk9fAimbW9vM?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Why an ugly `ngSwitch` with only one `ngSwitchWhen` instead of a simple `ngIf`? And why a partial here, instead of a directive?

Comment: @Blackhole Because I am not sure which version of AngularJS the OP uses. But I am sure `ng-switch`works in all version. 'ng-if' is only available in 1.1.5+ I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach written as a directive ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux32e/9/)):

```
angular.module('the-app', []).directive('arbitraryNesting', [
'$compile', 
function($compile){
  var template = '\
<li ng-repeat="datum in data">{{datum.title}}\
  <ul ng-if="datum.children && datum.children.length > 0" arbitrary-nesting="datum.children">\
  </ul>\
</li>';

  var compiledTemplate;

  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: { 'data': '=arbitraryNesting' },
      terminal: true,
      link: function(scope, element) {
          compiledTemplate = compiledTemplate || $compile(template);

          var newScope = scope.$new();

          var linked = compiledTemplate(newScope);
          element.append(linked);
      }
  }
}])
```