# Angular - Make nested list from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of JSON data that I would like to display in a nested list:

The JSON comes in the following format:

```
["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", ["Nested Item 1", "Nested Item 2"]]
```

The html should be:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Nested Item 1</li>
      <li>Nested Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't have control of the JSON, and it may be deeper than 2 levels.

Of course, I tried this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

but it doesn't work because for nested items, it simply displays the json.

How can I achieve nested lists in AngularJs?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7ax7tsa/

Comment: Recursive directive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618106/unknown-number-of-sublists-with-angularjs/20618894#20618894

Comment: @Blackhole Could you explain how that works or give some documentation?

Comment: The question linked by zsong gives an idea, but Google will help you if you want to go further.

Comment: @Blackhole Thanks, it helped me answer my own question. Should this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Yep, this will be done by the community, don't worry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to zsong and Blackhole.

Resulting HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/nestedList.html">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in data">
                <div ng-switch="isString( item )">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">{{item}}</div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="false">
                        <!-- Recursive template!! -->
                        <div ng-include="'/nestedList.html'" ng-init="data = item">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <div ng-include="'/nestedList.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used a recursive template which included itself. It borrows heavily on the answer of [Unknown number of sublists with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618106/unknown-number-of-sublists-with-angularjs/20618894). In addition, I had to add the following code to the controller:

```
$scope.isString = function (item) {
    return typeof item === "string";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this nice [blog post](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/) that has a complete example at the end. In short you need to build nested directives, where inner directive will have recursive call to outer directive:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
        <collection collection='tasks'></collection>
    </div>
</body>

angular.module('APP', [])
.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        ...
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member'></member></ul>"
    }
})
.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    return {
        ...
        template: "<li>{{member.name}}</li>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children)) {
                element.append("<collection collection='member.children'></collection>"); 
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
```