# How to develop Nth level of nested tabular output by using angular js ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

out of curiosity i like to know can we develop Nth level of nested tabular output by using angular js ng-repeat.

here is one screen shot attached because other people can understand what kind of output i am after. basically i have to show manager and employee relation info in nested format. a manager can have many employee and each employee can again manager of other employee. in this scenario it is not know how many nesting could be show by ng-repeat. so give me honest feedback that this kind of nth level nested output can be achieve by ng-repeat or do i need to look for any angular free grid. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this type of a pattern with ng-repeat and ng-include to create a nested grid with an unknown number of nestings.

[ng-repeat unknown number of nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294932/ng-repeat-unknown-number-of-nested-elements)

Comment: thanks but how can i load detail row dynamically when user click on parent. any idea.