# How to show hierarchical data in tabular format using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular. so i was reading write up just to accomplish my job. this way i will try but not sure that am i going in right direction? here is my sample code

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="parent in items">{{parent.pitem}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="child in parent.citems">{{child.pitem }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{ "pitem": "Coffee", "citems": "" }, { "pitem": "Tea", "citems": [{ "pitem": "Black tea", "citems": "" }, { "pitem": "Green tea", "citems": "" }] }, { "pitem": "Milk", "citems": "" }]
});
```

[image]

i actually i need to show employee hierarchy like manager and their subordinate.

i also read this too on the same kind of topic written by @zsong https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295177/6188148

so please help me to generate tabular output with ng-repeat using `ul,li` and end user should be able to expand collapse rows too. please have a look at this url http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/examples/example-bootstrap-3.html i want similar kind of output but with ng-repeat.

see this url http://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/angularjs/treegrid/tree-grid-filter.aspx  then can understand what kind of output i am trying to build with ng-repeat.

please guide and suggestion.

Comment: why negative when i am showing my effort.

Comment: You have to go recursive so you need to inject DOM with ng-repeat instead of writing down your ng-repeat in the DOM as a declaration

Comment: why don't use angular tree view. see this sample http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

Comment: i am trying to know how to generate output like tree grid using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/NP7P5/ shows exactly what you are looking for:

Recursion

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
        {{ category.title }}
        <ul ng-if="category.categories">
            <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Json object

```
$scope.categories = [
  { 
    title: 'Computers',
    categories: [
      {
        title: 'Laptops',
        categories: [
          {
            title: 'Ultrabooks'
          },
          {
            title: 'Macbooks'            
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        title: 'Desktops'
      },

      {
        title: 'Tablets',
        categories: [
          { 
            title: 'Apple'
          },
          {
            title: 'Android'
          }
        ]        
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    title: 'Printers'
  }

];

});
```

Comment: what so special about your code. you code is giving same output like mine. i want child data should not be shown rather there will be collapse icon before each child data and when user click on collapse icon then expand icon come and child data will be show and user can  again click on expand icon to ma ethe data collapse like tree view.

Comment: i am trying to know how to generate output like tree grid using ng-repeat.

Comment: see this url http://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/angularjs/treegrid/tree-grid-filter.aspx  then can understand what kind of output i am trying to build with ng-repeat.