# How to create dynamic tree structure left menu angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, treeview

I need to create dynamic tree structure left menu in my web app using angular js from json response.  I achieved this with the help of ng-repeat with the limitation of 3 levels - Level 1 -> Parent(Category), Level 2 -> child(subcategories), Level 3 -> child of child(subcategories).  Now, I want 'n' no. of levels without restriction. There is an option to create a category as parent and can create sub category under that parent.  Just like google drive.

Anyone can guide me to accomplish this.

Following is the json response.

```
        {
  "categories": [
    {
      "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:05.422Z",
      "category": "Technical Department",
      "count": 0,
      "_id": "59de15d5305f34741de250a1",
      "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:05.422Z",
      "subcategories": [
        {
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:01:02.247Z",
          "category": "Management Team",
          "count": 0,
          "_id": "59de160e305f34741de250a5",
          "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:01:02.247Z",
          "parent": "59de15d5305f34741de250a1",
          "subcategories": [
            {
              "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:03:32.781Z",
              "category": "Team 02",
              "count": 0,
              "_id": "59de16a4305f34741de250a7",
              "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:03:32.781Z",
              "parent": "59de160e305f34741de250a5"
            },
            {
              "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:03:22.491Z",
              "category": "Team 01",
              "count": 0,
              "_id": "59de169a305f34741de250a6",
              "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:03:22.491Z",
              "parent": "59de160e305f34741de250a5"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:45.896Z",
          "category": "iOS Team",
          "count": 0,
          "_id": "59de15fd305f34741de250a4",
          "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:45.896Z",
          "parent": "59de15d5305f34741de250a1",
          "subcategories": [
            {
              "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:11:50.399Z",
              "category": "Team 01",
              "count": 0,
              "_id": "59de1896305f34741de250b2",
              "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:11:50.399Z",
              "parent": "59de15fd305f34741de250a4"
            },
            {
              "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:11:38.820Z",
              "category": "Team 02",
              "count": 0,
              "_id": "59de188a305f34741de250b1",
              "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:11:38.820Z",
              "parent": "59de15fd305f34741de250a4"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:27.343Z",
          "category": "Android Team",
          "count": 0,
          "_id": "59de15eb305f34741de250a3",
          "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:27.343Z",
          "parent": "59de15d5305f34741de250a1"
        },
        {
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:17.443Z",
          "category": "Java Team",
          "count": 0,
          "_id": "59de15e1305f34741de250a2",
          "createdAt": "2017-10-11T13:00:17.443Z",
          "parent": "59de15d5305f34741de250a1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is the HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="category in docCategories" class="subpage" style="padding-left:0;">
                                <a href="javascript://void(0)"  ng-click="showsub1fn($index,category.category,category._id);libraryFilter(category._id,$index);" class="filsecnbdyseta3" ng-class="{clrGry : chekindex == $index}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true" ng-if="showsub1 != $index"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-folder-open " aria-hidden="true" style="color:#666b6e;" ng-if="showsub1 == $index" ng-class="{clrGry : chekindex == $index}"></i>
                                {{category.category}} <span ng-if="category.count > 0">({{category.count}})</span></a>
                                <span ng-repeat="cat1 in category.subcategories"  class="subpage" ng-show="showsub1 == $parent.$index">
                                    <a class="addnewDynCls" href="javascript://void(0)"  ng-click="showsub2fn($index,$parent.$index,cat1.category,cat1._id);libraryFilter(cat1._id,$index);" class="filsecnbdyseta3" ng-class="{clrGry : chekindexsub1 == $index}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-folder fafoopenot" aria-hidden="true" id="fold{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open fafoopen" aria-hidden="true" id="foldopen{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}" style="display:none;"></i>
                                    {{cat1.category}} <span ng-if="cat1.count > 0">({{cat1.count}})</span></a>
                                    <span class="subsubpagePrnt" id="showsub2{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}" style="display:none;">
                                        <span ng-repeat="cat2 in cat1.subcategories"  class="subpage subsubpage"  >
                                            <a class="addnewDynClsSub" href="javascript://void(0)"  ng-click="showsub3fn($index,$parent.$index,$parent.$parent.$index,cat2.category,cat2._id);libraryFilter(cat2._id,$index);" class="filsecnbdyseta3" ng-class="{clrGry : chekindexsub2 == $index}" >
                                                <i class="fa fa-folder fafoopenotsub" aria-hidden="true" id="fold{{$parent.$parent.$index}}f{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open fafoopensub" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#59b0dd;"  id="foldopen{{$parent.$parent.$index}}f{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}" style="display:none;"></i>

                                            {{cat2.category}} <span ng-if="cat2.count > 0">({{cat2.count}})</span></a>
                                            <span id="showsub3{{$parent.$parent.$index}}f{{$parent.$index}}f{{$index}}"></span>
                                            <!-- <span ng-repeat="cat3 in cat2.subcategories"  class="subpage">
                                                <a href="javascript://void(0)"  !ng-click="libraryFilter(category.category,$index)" class="filsecnbdyseta3" !ng-class="{clrBlk : chekindex == $index}">-{{cat3.category}}</a>
                                            </span> -->
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
```

JS for show/hiding folders in the menu

```
$scope.showsub1fn = function(ind,categoryName,categoryId){
    $scope.addCatBtn = false;
    $scope.categoryLevel = 1;
    $scope.levelOneIndex = ind;
    if($scope.showsub1 == ind){
        $scope.showsub1 = -1;
    }else{
        $scope.showsub1 = ind;
    }
    $scope.chekindex = ind;
    $scope.chekindexsub1 = -1;
    $scope.chekindexsub2 = -1;      
    $scope.categoryId = categoryId; 
    $(".addnewDynCls").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".addnewDynClsSub").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopenot").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopen").removeClass("clrGry");
    $('.subsubpage').hide();
    $(".fafoopenotsub").show();
    $(".fafoopensub").hide();       
    $(".fafoopenot").show();
    $(".fafoopen").hide();
    $('.dpdwnLib1').show();
 }
  $scope.showsub2fn = function(ind,parInd,categoryName1,categoryId1){
    $scope.addCatBtn = false;
    if($("#foldopen"+parInd+"f"+ind).css("display") == "inline"){
        $(".fafoopenot").show();
        $(".fafoopen").hide();
        $("#foldopen"+parInd+"f"+ind).show();
        $("#fold"+parInd+"f"+ind).hide();
        $(".subsubpagePrnt").hide();
        $("#showsub2"+parInd+"f"+ind).show();
    }else{
        $(".fafoopenot").show();
        $(".fafoopen").hide();
        $("#foldopen"+parInd+"f"+ind).hide();
        $("#fold"+parInd+"f"+ind).show();
        $(".subsubpagePrnt").hide();
        $("#showsub2"+parInd+"f"+ind).hide();
    }
    $scope.categoryLevel = 2;
    $scope.levelOneIndex = parInd;
    $scope.levelTwoIndex = ind;
    $('.subsubpage').show();
    $("#showsub2"+parInd+"f"+ind).toggle();
    $("#fold"+parInd+"f"+ind).toggle();
    $(".fafoopenot").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopen").removeClass("clrGry");
    $("#fold"+parInd+"f"+ind).addClass("clrGry");
    $("#foldopen"+parInd+"f"+ind).toggle();
    $("#foldopen"+parInd+"f"+ind).addClass("clrGry");       
    $(".addnewDynCls").removeClass("clrGry");
    $("#showsub2"+parInd+"f"+ind).siblings(".addnewDynCls").addClass("clrGry");
    $(".addnewDynClsSub").removeClass("clrGry");        
    $scope.chekindex = parInd;
    $scope.chekindexsub1 = ind;     
    $(".fafoopenotsub").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopensub").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopenotsub").show();
    $(".fafoopensub").hide();
    $('.dpdwnLib1').hide();
    $('.dpdwnLib2').show();

 }
 $scope.showsub3fn = function(ind,parInd,parparInd,categoryName2,categoryId2){
    $scope.addCatBtn = true;
    $scope.categoryLevel = 3;
    $scope.levelOneIndex = parparInd;
    $scope.levelTwoIndex = parInd;
    $scope.levelThreeIndex = ind;
    if($("#foldopen"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).css("display") == "inline"){
        $(".fafoopenotsub").show();
        $(".fafoopensub").hide();
        $("#foldopen"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).show();
        $("#fold"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).hide();
    }else{
        $(".fafoopenotsub").show();
        $(".fafoopensub").hide();
        $("#foldopen"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).hide();
        $("#fold"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).show();
    }
    $(".addnewDynClsSub").removeClass("clrGry");        
    $(".fafoopenotsub").removeClass("clrGry");
    $(".fafoopensub").removeClass("clrGry");
    $("#showsub3"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).siblings(".addnewDynClsSub").addClass("clrGry");
    $("#fold"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).toggle();
    $("#fold"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).addClass("clrGry");
    $("#foldopen"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).toggle();
    $("#foldopen"+parparInd+"f"+parInd+"f"+ind).addClass("clrGry");     
    $('.dpdwnLib1').hide();
    $('.dpdwnLib2').hide();
    $('.dpdwnLib3').show();
 }
```

[image: I also need to show breadcrumb, in which level the current folder selected]

Comment: Still no luck..

Comment: Check this: [ng-repeat unknown number of nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294932/ng-repeat-unknown-number-of-nested-elements)